# Q: How to update firmware correctly

Tags: updates, dock, firmware

[image]
I'm looking at the screen and I'm wondering how to update the firmware suggested here, while not using the dock.

My question is on how. Don't I, in order to update the firmware, have to be connected to the dock? If I'm connected to it, am I not using it? This reminds me the days where win95 requested you to connect to the internet to download the drivers for the modem.

2nd (site question): How safe is this? Knowing that the dock is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. As no οne answered I thought to give it a try. My thoughts was on how to update the firmware of a device that I'm using if the installation instructions say "Only offline"!!!.

**The sort answer is "you do it anyway and the device will disconnect and connect back again during the process, all by it self"!!!** Nice.

So as I'm not a GUI guy I did via terminal and it was quite simple. Just 2 commands.

```
sudo fwupdmgr refresh
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

If there is an update to any of the connected devices, after the 2nd command there will be a prompt, asking you if you want to proceed with the update. If you do concern and hit `Y`, the update will start and in some point the dock will restart it self. Don't panic. This is what it supposed to do. After that the dock will connect to laptop again and.... that's it.

I however did one more thing. I disconnected the laptop and power down the dock by removing the power cable. After 5 sec I powered back up the dock and the fans of the dock  went crazy for about a minute. I don't know if that was needed but I did it anyway. After that all was OK and my laptop is "docked" again with no problems.

note:
In case you don't have `fwupdmgr`, just run `sudo apt install fwupd`.